# Is it possible to align 3 Views side by side with same width in auto layout by only using interfacebuilder?

Tags: ios, xcode6, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a quick question according auto layout. Maybe I am missing something, but since two hours  I am trying to align 3 views next to each other with same width. My goal is that each view is using 1/3 of the screens with. After autorotation all views should have each the same width, but all views next to each other should have a total width of the superview.

My idea looks like this:

[image]

Doing this programmatically is kind of easy. Is it possible to solve this task by only using interface builder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. set the three views to have an equal width
2. set view1's leading constraint to superview to have a constant of 0
3. set view1's trailing constraint to view2 to have a constant of 0
4. set view2's trailing constraint to view3 to have a constant of 0
5. set view3's trailing constraint to superview to have a constant of 0

Comment: I'm not really sure what you exactly mean. After setting equal width what else are you setting? Horizontal spacing? Center in container? Whatever I try, it's not working. Stefans answer works out of the box. Your idea could be a nice solution, too. But I just don't understand it.

Comment: I see the changes. Just trying.

Comment: here you have a quick demo project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0i4btulsex5kwth/AACg2xzya0O8zdi430RoX_sba?dl=0

Comment: I tried this manually, but interface builder is not offering a connection from view2 to view3 in the combo box for the trailing constraint. That was my problem before. Sometimes I have an idea, but interface builder doesn't let me choose the view I would like to use. Do you know how I can force which vie is to be used?

Comment: to get that connection offered you have to make sure that your views are not overlapping in storyboard. think of the whole width of the view as coordinates from 1 to 100. when view2 ends at 70 and view3 starts at 68 you won't get that connection offered. you have to make sure that your view3 starts at a minimum of 70 (the end of view2) when you set up the constraints. know what i mean?

Comment: another option is to ctrl drag from view2 to view3 and choose horizontal spacing! after that make sure that the constant of the just created constraint is 0!

Comment: Great! I've hat a similar idea but interface builder never offered the connection to me. Now I know why. @Stefan Salatic: I like your answer, too. It's the numeric way of doing things. There is a lot of cases where your option is great. For people who like numbers more than drag and drop it's the better way. Especially if the segments should have different sizes. However, I could reproduce both of your answers now. I decided to accept Andre Slottas answer, because he gave me the hint why my approach was not working before. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes just set it as the same size as parent view (then change it to 1:3 ratio) and set leading constraints to 0. You do this by ctrl dragging the view you want to it's super view. There you select the `Equal Widths` property.

Like this, but 1:3 ratio

[image]

Comment: Silly me! Of course, I can use the superview for the "same width" parameter. Thanks a lot! Sometimes live is so easy.

Comment: But if you have a view construction like [1/3][1/6][1/6][1/3], then this solution is very powerful!